# Parallel sprints in Scrum - one project, two teams

Tags: scrum, sprint, jira

Currently, I am working on the project that consists of two teams which we track also in the JIRA software tool and it is basically two teams that are working on the same project so this is my question and concern:

- Should we create parallel sprints (they start and end at the same time) for the X and Y team and then track their progress parallelly?

**The reason why we can't handle this in one single sprint:** X team is always delivering first their implementation (API) so after they finish, Y team can start.

Comment: Do you expect Team Y to accept the work from Team X in the middle of the Sprint?

Comment: No, the idea is that team X is always one iteration ahead of team Y, so basically, the team Y will accept team X implementation in their sprint and team X will do their implementation for the team Y in their sprint.

Comment: Why would you *not* create parallel sprints in Jira?

Comment: I 've created parallel sprints, I think this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

In Jira, your really only have three viable options. You can have one Jira project with two boards and one Sprint per board, you can have one Jira project with one board and one Sprint and use quick filters to toggle the issues that appear, or you can have multiple Jira projects. The first and third options are the least clumsy, and if you needed a view of both teams, you can just create a third board.

Personally, I'd lean toward the third approach of multiple projects. If you have an API and then consumers of that API, it seems like you have two or more releasable entities. By having separate projects, you can better take advantage of the Jira versioning capabilities, releases, components, and some of the other fields. There's more meaningful context behind the values since it relates to one and only one releasable entity.

I'd also want to take a strong look at how you manage dependencies between teams. I'd want to try to decouple these teams. Improved visibility may help, though.